# Create a particular {x,y} list

Tags: list-manipulation

How is it possible to create a list of {x,y} points as the following one:

`list={{1,1},{1,2},...,{1,100},{2,1},{2,2},...,{2,100},...,{100,1},{100,2},...,{100,100}}`

Thanks

Comment: `Table[{i,j}, {i, 100}, {j, 100}]`? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I was using Range, but it doesn't work for 2D  lists. However, you answer gives my some additional brackets that are unwanted, like this: {{{1,1},{1,2},...,{1,100},{2,1},{2,2},...,{2,100},...,{100,1},{100,2},...,{100,100}}}. I've found the way with Flatten[]. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but a more general topic. Let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: @Michele You need to `Flatten` the result; consider `Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 100}], 1]`. More in general, also take a look at the proposed duplicate.

Comment: `Join @@ Array[List , {100, 100} ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Tuples[Range[100], 2]
```

or using `Table` as mentioned in the comment

It is worth noting that the method relying on `Tuples` is 10-12 times faster than `Table`